Debugging Console-App not working. No C# project is currently loaded. Please create a C# project in order to debug
I’m currently learning C# through a beginner course provided by Microsoft. I followed the instructor's steps precisely, but I keep encountering an error.
Here are the steps I followed:

Created a new Console App using the command dotnet new console inside Powershell.

Opened the project in VS Code with code .

Installed the C# extension.

Attempted to debug Program.cs using the F5 key.


Despite following these steps, I keep receiving the error:
"No C# project is currently loaded. Please create a C# project in order to debug."

Do you have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?
Edit: Here is a Screenshot


You have program.cs open.  Seems your error message says that VSCode wants you to open the project file instead.  Try opening the project file (csproj), and then running the code again.

There are several ways to start debugging, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugging So you should try to see if other options work for you. F5 relies on automatic project detection, so it might not always work out.

I found the solution: the issue was due to the absence of the .vscode folder when creating the project via CLI. Thank you for your ideas and tips!

After several attempts, I identified the issue. It turns out that the problem was due to the absence of the .vscode folder.
To resolve this, follow these steps to create the .vscode folder with the necessary launch.json and tasks.json files:
Press Shift + P and type .NET: Generate Assets for Building and Debugging, then press Enter.
Press F5 to start debugging.
And just like that, you’re all set! Welcome to the world of debugging.
